# The application could not be started Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

i using Xamarin after run app in my mobile dives huawei give me this message error

The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).
Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.

Comment: Did you look in configuration manager to make sure the Droid project is set to deploy:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the Package name to another name
Right click project and select Properties > Android Manifest > Package name
rename it to another.

example:
If old Package name is 
(com.xamarin.acquaintforms)
 Changed to new name 
(com.xamarin.acquaintforms.v2)